# how to restrict text area that wouldn't allow ONLY blank spaces as input

Tags: jquery, trim

i was trying to use the .trim()function but it would still allow a whitespace as an input.

TA= $('textarea').trim();

any help is Much appreciated :)

Comment: you meant whitespaces at both beginning and end of the line or between lines/para too ??

Comment: Do you want to prevent user to use spaces in textarea ?

Comment: @Makesh at the beginning only.

Comment: @A.P. First input only, those long input of whitespaces in a textarea...

Answer (score 2):

You could prevent it from being added at all by checking whether the key pressed is the space bar and returning false at first time if so:

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    type="text/javascript">
          ​$("textarea").on("keydown", function (e) {
          var c = $("textarea").val().length;
          if(c == 0)
              return e.which !== 32;
          });​​​​​
 </script>
```

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/eL9u8dto/3/)

Comment: @Jan what's your exact requirement? As my answered code prevent user to use space at the beginning of statement but then it allows to use space. Now please tell me, what's your exact requirement ?

Comment: @Jan are you missing to import  latest version of jQuery ? Look my answer how to import that.

Answer (score 1):

Try with keyup event

```
 $("#text-area").keyup(function(e){

    if(this.value.match(" ")){
        this.value = this.value.replace(" ", "");
    }

});
```

It will remove the space when u type space on that textarea.

As your requirement try this one with change event

```
 $("#text-area").change(function(e){
        this.value = this.value.trim();
});
```

Comment: what u actually want. To remove space or to restrict space ??

Comment: Oh then u should mention it. then just trim Like this.value = this.value.trim();
no condition check is required

Comment: your last method how applicable here ? i thing in each keyup it will fired

Comment: ya if you restrict the it will applicable. Otherwise you can just do it in change event

Answer (score 0):

First of all your question is unclear. i think you are looking for a solution where in your text area white space is not allowded.
Then you can use the following method

**html**

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="textarea" >
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById('textarea').addEventListener('keydown', function (e){

  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
      e.returnValue = false;
      return false;
    }

}, false);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zo0s5vmy/)**

IF you want to avoid the white space in starting just use trim

```
var yourstring=document.getElementById('textareaid').value;
    yourstring.trim();
```

**UPDATE**

**html**

```
<textarea id="text1"></textarea>
```

**javascript**

```
$("#text1").on("keydown", function (e) {
    var len = $("#text1").val().length;
    if(len == 0)
    {
        return e.which !== 32;
    }
    else 
    {
      var pos=$("#text1").getCursorPosition();
         if(pos==0)
       {


           return e.which !== 32;

       }

    }

});

$("#text1").on("keyup", function (e) {
var pos=$("#text1").getCursorPosition();
       if(pos==0)
       {

           var values =$("#text1").val();
            if(values.charAt(0)==' ')
            {
                values=values.trim();
                $("#text1").val(values);
            }
           return e.which !== 32;

       }
});

(function ($, undefined) {
    $.fn.getCursorPosition = function() {
        var el = $(this).get(0);
        var pos = 0;
        if('selectionStart' in el) {
            pos = el.selectionStart;
        } else if('selection' in document) {
            el.focus();
            var Sel = document.selection.createRange();
            var SelLength = document.selection.createRange().text.length;
            Sel.moveStart('character', -el.value.length);
            pos = Sel.text.length - SelLength;
        }
        return pos;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

check the working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b8s678b1/2/)**

Comment: how did you try that ??/ did you use any event handlers ?? or direct put this code to javascript ?

Comment: hi, thanks for your help, but what i want is, that it will restrict 'long' whitespaces at the first input only, thanks.. :(

Comment: long white space means ? user click space  key continuesly or hold the space key for a while

Comment: clicking continuously and longpress :(

Comment: did you check the  js fiddle in the above comment? it will restrict long space press and first white space everything ...what ever the value it will trim the first white space

Comment: or did you want to restrict space at first,i mean the user can' enter a white space at starting

Comment: i just don't know how or why, but it doesn't work on me... my text area has something else, it has 'text editor' stuff, does it matter?

Comment: @Jan you can refer my updated answer, i think it will satisfy your needs